# location.hash reload the HTML again and again on Blackberry 6.0

Tags: javascript, blackberry, cordova, jqtouch

My phonegap based application which uses JQTouch and JQuery works fine on iPhone, Android, Chrome. But it does not work properly on Blackberry 6.0. I was able to find the problem, the problem is in jqtouch.js following is the way to reach that line:

```
jqtouch.js > animatePages-function > callback-private function
```

in private callback function they defined

```
location.hash = "#"+ id;
```

whenever my application reaches to this line it re-renders whole HTML file and so the application restarts. I am not able to find any solution for this. Is there any other way to do this? I tried to put `window.event.preventDefault()` but it throws error.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the problem, I replaced `"location.hash"` with 
`history.pushState( {}, document.title, ("#"+id) );` 
 wherever jqtouch try to assign new value to `location.hash` and it is working fine on Blackberry 6.0

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in JQTouch that I solved by using non-real hashes when setting my location. If your hash is an actual id, the page jumps to the element. Just add "page" or something to the end of your hash so it doesn't point to an element id:

```
location.hash = "#" + id + "page";
```